# OpenCV value cvWaitKey when the Num Lock is enabled

Tags: opencv

How to determine whether a button is pressed <kbd>q</kbd> when the `NumLock` is enabled

```
if (cvWaitKey(0) == 'q')
  cout <<"you press: q";
```

when the `NumLock` is enabled, does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a laptop where the 'q' key is on the keyboard then cvWaitkey can't do that - the operating system just tells it the ascii code for the key.

You should call cvWaitkey(0) to run the openCV event loop and then check the keyboard scancodes with whatever function your OS provides